# Off-topic > belongs to another site

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I think it would be good to have "Close > Off-topic > belongs to another site" options containing:

- [academia.se](https://academia.stackexchange.com/),
- [math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

For academia.se, there is [already a question](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/783/42) that would fit better there (and more are comming...).

As for mathematics.se, I suspect there will be some influx of "do my homework" questions (perhaps even with effort shown) just by having "mathematics" in the name. If it doesn't happen, we could always change this later.

What do you think?

Comment: I would also add http://mathoverflow.net if the questions gets too advanced and off-topic.

Comment: @MarkusKlein Perhaps, but I doubt many such advanced questions will happen here, I would say that people with advanced questions would frequently find mathoverflow.net themselves. I don't know how many slots there are (meta, academia and math constitute already 3).

Comment: @dtldarek: We can have three predefined custom close reasons, but I do not know whether predefined migration targets count. Meta as a migration target certainly does not count, however. I agree that we only should have custom predefined close reasons for cases that are likely to appear, and *belongs to MathOverflow* is most likely not among them.

Comment: Don't forget that moderators can migrate to any site, so if we don't have it in the list then it can still be flagged for migration to another site.  So I'd go with academia and math(s) but not MO and then see what happens.

Comment: Does anybody know how to make it happen?

Comment: @dtldarek: AFAIK, two moderators have to agree on a new predefined close reason.

Comment: Another possible migration target is stats.stackexchange.com, for example for questions like http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/851/what-kind-of-a-mean-value-is-this.

Comment: The question I referred to was removed by the author and reposted here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/727653/what-kind-of-a-mean-value-is-this  It seems reasonable for either math.SE or stats.SE to me.

Answer (score 3):

At the very least, I agree that we ought to be able to migrate questions to Math Stack Exchange.  We have already had one question that fit the bill:

https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/808/dot-product-for-vectors

And I expect that there will be many others.

Comment: Yes, no doubt about that. But still I am pretty sure we will not get a path (via voting) before we are out of beta.

Comment: @quid I agree.  None of the other betas I'm aware of have this feature.  If we start getting overwhelmed by such questions, though, it couldn't hurt to ask for it.

Comment: Let us hope we will not get that overwhelmed! :-) But yes perhaps they make an exception.

Comment: @quid: Apparently, we are not getting overwhelmed, but it seems that math.se is the most common place for closed off-topic questions.

Comment: @Roland yes, this is the case. The absolute number is quite low though, something like 5 over the last 30 days. I am not sure if you comment is a suggestion for some action on my side. If it is, please be more direct, as currently I do not understand what precisely you would like me to do.

Comment: @quid: If you can manage to include math.se into the possible redirections, this would be great. The reason I made this comment was that I just stumbled over a (now deleted) question and was about to post a meta question when I realized that there's this one already. My comment was mainly meant as a reviving of this topic. If you think that a path is not yet necessary, it's also fine for me.

Comment: @Roland thank you for the explanation. In fact I saw that question, too, OP self-deleted and asked it then on math.SE. For the migration path, this is not up to me. We would have to ask the SE staff, and as I said in my answer I doubt they will open it as long as we are in beta. What we can do rather easity is have a costum off-topic reason saying roughly "this site is not for math question asked them on math.SE". I will have a look through the closed question we had and make a post later today.

Answer (score 1):

This is in principle a good point to raise, but it is not possible to have migration path (for migration via voting) *to* a site in beta, and I thus strongly believe it is not possible to have migration path from a site in beta either (also as there is AFAIK no one-wath path). Thus, this is debate while relevant seems premature at the moment (certainly as regards academia.SE as that site is still in beta, too, but I believe altogether).

As said in comments, moderators can still migrate. Thus, the way to proceed for the nearer future  presumably should be to flag the question as 'other' and asking for migration. However, I think initially migrations should only be done in extremely clear  cases. What is and is not on-topic is not full decided yet and while a closure is easily reversed this is not really the case for a migration. [One could have costum off-topic reasons, too, but I would wait and see how frequent which type of off-topic actually is before introducing them. Meanwhile, costum closure reason or comments could be used.]

Some more technical points related to comments: the migration paths do not count among the costum off-topic reasons, neither by number nor by the way they are create. The number of migration path is at most 4 (excluding meta, I think). Migration path can only by opened by developpers, by contrast off-topic reasons can be created by site's moderators (one proposes another approves, I think). In general, developpers are very careful when opening such paths. We should not expect to get too many.

Abstracly, I agree that the two most natural pathes are academia.SE and math.SE. However, for the reasons mentioned at the start at the moment we cannot get pathes and thus we might delay the debate until we have more data.

Comment: We could still make a predefined close reason that does not lead to instant migration (as far as I understand it). [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) has one for Stack Overflow for example.

Comment: Yes, we could, as I said in my answer. :-)  "One could have costum off-topic reasons, too, but I would wait and see how frequent which type of off-topic actually is before introducing them."